# Scrapy-Selenium: Output contains 'None' value

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I am trying to execute this script using Scrapy-Selenium middleware to handle JavaScript. This script is not showing any error but provides 'None' output. I think I am missing something from this

```
followers = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/goat/followers/']"))).click()
            time.sleep(3)
```

particular line but I am unable to figure it out. What am I actually missing here? I am stuck at this point very badly.

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from scrapy.selector import Selector 
from goat.settings import * 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By import time


class FollowersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'followers'

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.instagram.com"
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('__headless')
 
        chrome_path = SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/goat/")
        
        #target username
        username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")))
        password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))

        #enter username and password
        username.clear()
        username.send_keys("username")
        time.sleep(2)

        password.clear()
        password.send_keys("password")
        time.sleep(2)

        #target the login button and click it
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
        time.sleep(2)
        #We are logged in!

        #closing pop_up
        pop_up = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]"))).click()
        time.sleep(2)
        #closing notification pop_up
        notification_pop_up = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]"))).click()
        time.sleep(2)

        #search_box
        searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']")))
        searchbox.clear()
        keyword = "@goat"
        searchbox.send_keys(keyword)
        # searchbox.send_keys(keyword, Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)

        select_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/goat/']"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)

        followers = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/goat/followers/']"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)
        
        
        select_follower = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  ']/a"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)


        self.html = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
        
        

    def parse(self, response):

        resp = Selector(text=self.html)

        links = resp.xpath("//span[@class='Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  ']/a")
        for link in links:

            yield {
                'Title': link.xpath(".//div[@class='XBGH5']/h2/text()").get(),
                'Posts': link.xpath("(.//span[@class='g47SY '])[1]/text()").get(),
                'Followers': link.xpath("(.//span[@class='g47SY '])[2]/text()").get()
            }
```

Comment: You have a .click() there. Use follows.click() after you set it. Or remove followers = .